# Best way to use MongoDB with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently using MongoDB native and I'm familiar with it.

Only thing I'm worrying about it is my source quality.

Because of the native driver's nature, nested loop is inevitable.

I have looked at Mongoose but I prefer schemaless way of using MongoDB.

And I could not make a choice among

```
mongodb-native, mongoose (using mix type), mongolian, mongous, mongoskin
```

Or is there a way or tutorial to use MongoDB native with keeping the source DRY?

Comment: Your question is basically: "how to avoid deep nesting with mongodb-native?" This has been answered by @Raynos. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5669435/45974

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mongodb-native will shortly be on the officially support driver list for mongoDB, so from that perspective, it is probably the safest choice.  Combine that (for quality of support) with the Raynos answer in the comments and that should make the choice for you.

Comment: Just to note, since this post the mongodb-native developer has been hired by 10gen and the driver is now on the officially supported list :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/ mongoose also become official

> Mongoose is the officially supported ODM for Node.js